# Will a teacher fluent in Irish be useful in learning pronunciation of Scottish Gaelic ( Gàidhlig ) Folk Songs?

Tags: irish, gaelic

My kids are hoping to learn some Gaelic folk songs. We have some folk songs we would like to learn such as Fear a Bhàta:

'S tric mi sealltainn o'n chnòc a's àirde
Dh'fheuch am faic mi fear a bhàta
An tig thu'n diùigh no'n tig thu màireach
'S mur tig thu idir gur truagh a tà' mi

Sèist:  Chorus (after each verse):

Fhir a bhata 'sna horo eile
Fhir a bhata 'sna horo eile
Fhir a bhata 'sna horo eile
Mo shòraidh slàn leat 's gach àit an teid thu

Tha mo chridhe-sa briste brùite
'S tric na deóir a ruith o'm shùilean
An tig thu nochd no'm bi mo dhùil riut
No'n dùin mi'n dorus le osna thùrsaich

Gheall mo leannan dhomh gùn dhe'n t-sìoda
Gheall e siod agus breacan rìomhach
Fainn òir anns an fàiginn iomhaigh
Ach 's eagal leam gun dean e di-chuimhn'

Bidh mi tuille gu tùrsach deùrach
Mar eala bhàn 's an déigh a reùbadh
Guileag bàis aic' air lochan feùrach
Is cach uile an déigh a tréigsinn

The only local teacher we can find on Gaelic to learn correct pronunciation is fluent in Irish.
Is the pronunciation similar to the point where we could learn to sing this recognizably with instruction from an Irish speaker, or is it better to either learn folk songs in Irish or try to find someone speaking Scottish Gaelic to learn this particular song.

Comment: Mostly just my opinion, but I’d go for finding a Scottish speaker. The pronunciation is similar enough that there’s some mutual comprehension, but different enough that you can’t really pronounce the other reliably unless you have significant experience with exposure to it. I’m a fairly fluent Irish speaker myself, and I’m constantly surprised by quirks of pronunciations in Scottish songs; I wouldn’t dare teach anyone anything but the very basics of Scottish pronunciation.